# XV6- scheduler for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, process, scheduler, xv6

i am working in implementing a new scheduler in my xv6 , and to do that i need to understand how its working 1st , i am facing a wired problem which is i cant really understand how the for loop loops throw the process

this is the original code :

```
void
scheduler(void){
  struct proc *p;

  for(;;){
  // Enable interrupts on this processor.
  sti();

 // Loop over process table looking for process to run.
 acquire(&ptable.lock);
 for(p = ptable.proc; p < &ptable.proc[NPROC]; p++){
   if(p->state != RUNNABLE)
     continue;

  // Switch to chosen process.  It is the process's job
  // to release ptable.lock and then reacquire it
  // before jumping back to us.
  proc = p;
  switchuvm(p);
  p->state = RUNNING;
  swtch(&cpu->scheduler, proc->context);
  switchkvm();

  // Process is done running for now.
  // It should have changed its p->state before coming back.
  proc = 0;
}
release(&ptable.lock);

 }
}
```

---

so i tried a simple thing , i made to for loops , the 1st one should loop throw all proc and count them with out doing any thing else , the 2nd one should loop and run them as the original one was doing , the thing is it didn't work as i expected , what is happening is that it run one cycle from the 1st for loop then it run one cycle from the 2nd and so on

```
void
scheduler(void)
{
struct proc *p;
int FirstCounter=0;
int SecCounter=0;
for(;;){
  // Enable interrupts on this processor.
  sti();
  // Loop over process table looking for process to run.
  acquire(&ptable.lock);
  for(p = ptable.proc; p < &ptable.proc[NPROC]; p++){
    if(p->state != RUNNABLE)
      continue;
    counter++;
    cprintf("1st counter  = %d\n",FirstCounter); 
}
    for(p = ptable.proc; p < &ptable.proc[NPROC]; p++){
      if(p->state != RUNNABLE)
        continue;

      // Switch to chosen process.  It is the process's job
      // to release ptable.lock and then reacquire it
      // before jumping back to us.
        proc = p;
        switchuvm(p);
        p->state = RUNNING;
        swtch(&cpu->scheduler, proc->context);
        switchkvm();



        // Process is done running for now.
        // It should have changed its p->state before coming back.
        proc = 0;
        cprintf("2nd counter  = %d\n",SecCounter); 
    }


release(&ptable.lock);
```

}
}

---

and the output is like that,

```
.
.
.
1st counter  = 14
2nd counter  = 15
1st counter  = 15
2nd counter  = 16
.
.
```

---

why is that happening ?

Comment: This can't be the code. FirstCounter, SecCounter, counter?!

Answer (score 0):

I tried, and got the same results.

But, when you print the pid of the process, you will find that the `pid = 1 and pid = 2`, I think they are init and page daemon process.

I have no idea of the prints for init process and page daemon process. But, when you try to `fork()`new process, you will get the prints as you thought.